# How to make multiple JTextFields write to one file

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextfield, bufferedwriter

I have a project involving a recipe book that saves info like ingredients, utilities, etc. and i need to make the fields that those details are entered in, save that text to a file. Each field is a JTextField. The only thing being saved is text to a .txt.
*the class is called recipereader, but i am only writing to the file*ignore the name* If i could get a response that showed what the code would look like that would be much appreciated. Also, i am using bufferedwriter so id like to keep within that unless its not possible.

```
PrintWriter outputStream=new PrintWriter("recipe001.txt");
outputStream.println(recipeName.getText());
outputStream.close();
```

recipeName is the JTextField.(and i know the code is wrong). i would like the content of each `JTextField`to be presented with one line, so thats why im doing `println.` Its quite simple but i do not know how to do the `getText` from the `JTextField` My frame is in another class from this code here

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: its up there could you please help

Comment: So, the file gets created but it's empty? Or what? Be more specific.

Comment: Why do you call the class RecipeReader when you are **writing** to the file?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

`RecipeReader` (or maybe it should be `RecipeWriter`?) should not know that the data comes from a Swing GUI. In other words, you need to design its methods to take `String` parameters with the data you want to store. Then the GUI code will call `getText()` from on each `JTextField` and send the `String`s to the method that writes the file.

You also need to be careful that when you open a file, it will be erased if it already exists. You probably should open the file once when the program starts and only close it when your program ends. That way you can continue to write to the file without deleting anything which you previously wrote to the file.

The other option is to open the file in "append" mode. I won't get into any more details here as there are plenty of online resources which explain how to do this.

**Original Answer:**

This will take some work on your part since `JTextField`s have no concept of a "file" built into them. You will need to open a file, get the contents of each text filed, and write them to the file. Be sure to close the file when you are done.

If you have trouble with any of these steps, please come back with a more specific question. Be sure to include code to illustrate what you have tried so far.

Comment: what you have said is actually exactly what ive been trying, however i just dont know the code to get me there

Comment: @OliverBath Like other people said before you need to be more specific in your question to get a more satisfying answer.  Where exactly are you stuck?